# C#: Is it wasteful to place Debug.Writeline text in a resource file?

Tags: c#, debugging, resources, release

I have the following: `Debug.Writeline(Properties.Resources.DEBUG_MSG_1);`

This works fine, and I can't imagine it hurting me in any way, shape, or form when compiling in Debug mode. However, I worry that although this is a nice and convenient way to manage my messages, it might be unnecessary overhead to include extra useless items in a resource file when I compile in Release. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: Why do your debug messages actually need to be in resources? DO you localize them?

Comment: Hmm, good point. I guess I was just trying to find a nice place to keep them all grouped. Perhaps I'll just place them as private consts and wrap them in a #if DEBUG directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... Resources are embedded to application. So in RELEASE you'll have some extra messages, which would not be used. The more you have them, the more will your application weights.

But I think that real problem might be someone reading DEBUG messages while she/he isn't supposed to do.

Answer (score 2):

The `WriteLine` method has the attribute

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
```

set. Thus I strongly assume that the compiler removes the function call automatically for release builds.

Comment: +1 The call is removed, but not the resource string which the OP is asking about.

Comment: But not the resource entries, which means that all the messages still end up being shipped with a production version...

Comment: In "good old" Visual C++ there was an option to conditionally define resources/resource symbols, too. Seems that this does not apply in C#/.NET, from what I know.